# Turn off Dropbox monitoring for selective directories inside of dropbox's monitor directory

Tags: dropbox

I have a folder directory for dropbox as follows

```
\My Dropbox
   \Project1
   \Project2
   \Project3
      \bin
```

I would like to stop dropbox from monitoring the bin directory but keep monitoring everything else.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please state which OS you're using! =) it might help

Comment: Indeed, I am using Windows 7 but the the answer looks to be the same for OSX and windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, using a feature called Selective Sync.

If you go into the advanced settings tab, and click the Selective Sync button you get a list of the directories directly inside your Dropbox folder. Pressing the advanced view button
allows you to go deeper into the folder structure, and, as you want to, stop certain folders from being synced.

Check out the article in the [Dropbox help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/175) for more info.

For example, on my system (OSX):

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/3P3s323W462y3Z0o2o2f/Screen%20shot%202011-02-10%20at%2022.32.10.png]

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I was using an old version that did not have the advanced tab option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use selective sync with Dropbox without understanding it first. It will delete the data from your local computer when you turn off syncing of a folder again.

As at is presently implemented, this option make almost no sense. You will most likely lose your bin directory.